# trying to email datarange.GetDataTable() as email body but only receiving "Datatable"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As title says, I am trying to compose an email with a Data Table that is supposed to show the current assignments of each team member but in the email I only get text "DataTable," Here is my code and my spreadsheet.

Spreadsheet: Deleted link due to workplace ethics.

```
  function sendemailsp1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B5:C14").getValues()

   for (var i=0; i<range.length; i++){
    if (range[i][0] == ""){

    var lr = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getLastRow()
    }
  }  


      var datarange = sheet.getRange(4, 2, lr-1, 2) ;
      var emaildata = datarange.getDataTable()


     MailApp.sendEmail("testemail@gmail.com", "test", emaildata) ;
    }
```

Comment: I think you can't see values inside datatable directly https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to GAS documentation, instances of DataTable can be passed around, but not manipulated. The DataTable class intentionally doesn't have any built-in methods, so you are pretty much limited to constructing charts.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-table

You could, however, convert Google Sheet to HTML using HtmlService and then pass it as 'htmlBody' parameter to the 'send' method of MailApp.

Project files:

[image: Project files]

In the example below, I fetch values from the 1st sheet and pass the value array to the pre-defined HTML template.

```
function createTable(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("table");

  template.values = values;

  var html = template.evaluate();

  return html.getContent(); 

}
```

Once you attach a variable to your HtmlTemplate as an object property, you can then reference it inside template file to build content dynamically. This can be achieved using inline "scriptlets". More on scriptlets and templated HTML here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets    Calling "evaluate()" method on HtmlTemplate will fire off the scriptlets and return an instance of HtmlOutput.

Invoking getContent() method on HtmlOutput will return the resulting html as a string.

table.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>

  table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  table {

  width: 100%;

  }

  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>

    <? var headers = values.shift(); ?>

    <tr>


  <?  for (var i=0; i < headers.length; i++) { ?>

    <th><?= headers[i]?></th>


   <? } ?>


    </tr>

    <? for (var j=0; j < values.length; j++) { ?>

    <tr>

    <? for (var k=0; k < values[j].length; k++) { ?>


    <td><?= values[j][k]?></td>


   <? } ?>


    </tr>
   <? }?>

    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Finally, here's the function that sends the email.

```
function sendEmail(){

  var table = getTable();

  MailApp.sendEmail(sender, subject, "", {htmlBody: table});
}
```

Result as seen in the sent email:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't see values inside datatable directly [developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-table](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-table)

If you just want to see values then you can simply do as follows

```
var emaildata = datarange.getValues().toString();
```